# How can I finetune a model from OpenAI's Whisper ASR on my own training data?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, openai-api, fine-tuning, openai-whisper

I use OpenAI's [Whisper](https://github.com/openai/whisper) python lib for speech recognition. I have some training data: either text only, or audio  + corresponding transcription. How can I finetune a model from OpenAI's Whisper ASR on my own training data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://github.com/openai/whisper/discussions/64, the released code doesn't contain the training/finetuning part. Therefore one would have to write it to be able to train/finetune a model from OpenAI's Whisper ASR on my own training data.

Also, from https://openai.com/blog/whisper/:

> We are open-sourcing models and inference code to serve as a foundation for building useful applications and for further research on robust speech processing.

No training code mentioned.

---

[William Castrillon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5408334/william-castrillon) and [nizata](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10689634/nizata) pointed to the following fine-tuning codes created by third-party developers:

- https://huggingface.co/blog/fine-tune-whisper ([code](https://huggingface.co/sanchit-gandhi/whisper-medium-switchboard-5k/blob/main/run_speech_recognition_whisper.py))
- https://github.com/openai/whisper/discussions/64
- https://huggingface.co/spaces/openai/whisper/discussions/6