# How to set up dataset and train whisper model from OpenAI with custom dataset

Tags: dataset, openai-whisper

I have a dataset, audios in wav format and transcripctions on excel file, how could i create a dataset to train whisper with my own data, most of the docs connect to hugging face cloud and call mozilla dataset with a magic method

Comment: [How can I finetune a model from OpenAI's Whisper ASR on my own training data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73841388/how-can-i-finetune-a-model-from-openais-whisper-asr-on-my-own-training-data)